# How to align the container to the right?

Tags: html, containers, panel

My current code renders like Picture 1, how can I get the output to render like Picture 2?

I tried to search the web but most of the results I have found show how to do this in `css`

Pic one,
[image]

Pic two,

[image]

```
                      <ext:Container id="Container1" runat="server" layout="HBoxLayout" width="2000" marginSpec="0 0 10 0" >
                        <Items>   
                      <ext:Panel ID="panel_cms004_view" Title="Document Control Profile" runat="server" AutoScroll="true" Region="East" Height="180" Width="700" Split="true">
                           <Loader ID="cms004_view" runat="server" Url="../CMS/cms004_view.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true" >
                                 <LoadMask ShowMask="true"></LoadMask>
                           </Loader>
                      </ext:Panel>  


                     <ext:Panel ID="panel_cms004d_audit" Title="Document Control Number - Audit" runat="server" AutoScroll="true" Region="East" Height="180" Width="428" Split="true">
                           <Loader ID="cms004d_audit" runat="server" Url="../CMS/cms004d_audit.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true" >
                                 <LoadMask ShowMask="true"></LoadMask>
                           </Loader>
                      </ext:Panel>

                      </Items>
                    </ext:Container>

                     <ext:Container id="Container8" runat="server" layout="HBoxLayout" width="2000" marginSpec="0 0 0 0">
                        <Items>   

                      <ext:Panel ID="docControlNum" Title="Document Control Number" runat="server" AutoScroll="true" Region="East" Height="265" Width="700" Split="true">
                           <Loader ID="cms004d_view" runat="server" Url="../CMS/cms004d_view.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true" >
                                 <LoadMask ShowMask="true"></LoadMask>
                           </Loader>
                      </ext:Panel>     
                        </Items>
                     </ext:Container>
```

Comment: Not really sure if that's what You want but try setting flow: left to both of them and then set margin-right to the left container.

Comment: Rather than using container layout 1 like you are doing now, try container layout 2. http://imgur.com/a/RUi4K

Comment: @josephting i want to do like container layout 2 but my code output is the container layout 1.. what should i change to get the result like container layout 2.

Comment: @David I'm not even sure what framework you're using but doing some Google search, it should be Ext.NET. I don't have extensive knowledge in using Ext.NET so you will have to figure it out yourself by just trying it out while referring to documentation and examples.
You might need to use nested containers. In other words, black box would be the main container, inside black container has 2 containers left and right. Place panel `panel_cms004_view` and `docControlNum` in left container and `panel_cms004d_audit` in right container.
http://imgur.com/eWMD8Tm

Comment: @josephting yes i'm using Ext.Net. thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whats the problem with CSS?
do something like this :

```
.right {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
      }
```

and then :

```
<div class="right">
 // your html
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                      <ext:Container id="Container1" runat="server" Height="700"  marginSpec="0 0 0 0" Layout="VBoxLayout" >
                        <Items>   
                      <ext:Panel ID="panel_cms004_view" Title="Document Control Profile" runat="server" AutoScroll="true" Height="180" Width="700" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                           <Loader ID="cms004_view" runat="server" Url="../CMS/cms004_view.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true" Height="200">
                                 <LoadMask ShowMask="true"></LoadMask>
                           </Loader>
                      </ext:Panel>  

                      <ext:Panel ID="docControlNum" Title="Document Control Number" runat="server" AutoScroll="true" Height="248" Width="700" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                           <Loader ID="cms004d_view" runat="server" Url="../CMS/cms004d_view.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true" Height="700">
                                 <LoadMask ShowMask="true"></LoadMask>
                           </Loader>
                      </ext:Panel>     


                      </Items>
                    </ext:Container>

                     <ext:Container id="Container8" runat="server" marginSpec="0 0 0 700" Layout="VBoxLayout" Height="700" Width="430">
                        <Items>   
                       <ext:Panel ID="panel_cms004d_audit" Title="Document Control Number - Audit" runat="server" AutoScroll="true" Height="425" Width="433"  Layout="VBoxLayout">
                           <Loader ID="cms004d_audit" runat="server" Url="../CMS/cms004d_audit.aspx" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="true" Height="700" Width="430" >
                                 <LoadMask ShowMask="true"></LoadMask>
                           </Loader>
                      </ext:Panel>
                        </Items>
                     </ext:Container>
```

Did some editing. Found out that need to add in the layout for the panel and the container.

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a .css I would recommend you to use preexisting css like twitter bootstrap css or even a frontend framework which they have function and features that works very well.
With Bootstrap it comes a Grid System where you can place your elements like you want.